# Auth login action not generating query in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I have a simple login form, just like the Cake Blog Tutorial.
It works like a charm when I use 'UsersController' and 'User' model naming conventions, passing the rights queries in debug.

But when I change it to other name, Alunos in my case, it generates no QUERY and give me 'Incorrect username and/or password.'.

My login.ctp

```
<H1> Login </H1>

<?php
    debug($this->data);
    echo $this->Form->create('Aluno', array('action' => 'login'));
    echo $this->Form->input('username');
    echo $this->Form->input('password');
    echo $this->Form->end('Login');
?>
```

My AppController

```
<?php

class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = array (
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array (
            'loginAction' => array ('controller'=>'alunos', 'action'=>'login'),
            'loginRedirect'=>array ('controller'=>'alunos', 'action'=>'inicio'),
            'logoutRedirect'=>array ('controller'=>'alunos', 'action'=>'index'),
            'authError'=>"Ops, você não está autorizado a fazer isso.",
            'authorize'=>array('Controller'),
        )
    );

    public function isAuthorized($user) {
        return true;
    }

    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->allow('index', 'add');
        $this->set('logged_in', $this->Auth->loggedIn());
        $this->set('current_user', $this->Auth->user());

    }

}
```

And my 'AlunosController.php' (see that its not USERSController, like common codes)

```
<?php

class AlunosController extends AppController {  

    public $name = 'Alunos';    

    public function beforeFilter(){
        parent::beforeFilter();
    }

    public function index() {}

    public function login(){
        debug($this->Auth->login());
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login()){
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Incorrect username and/or password.');
            }
        }
    }

    public function logout() {
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }

    public function add() {
        debug($this->Auth->login());
            if($this->request->is('post')) { 
                if ($this->Aluno->save($this->request->data)) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Cadastrado.');
                }else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Falha no cadastro.');
                }
            }   
    }

    public function inicio() {
        debug($this->Auth->login());
    }

}

?>
```

My debug($this->data) in login.ctp result:

```
array(
    'Aluno' => array(
        'password' => '*****',
        'username' => 'anyuser'
    )
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your app controller:

```
function beforeFilter() {

    $this->Auth->userModel = 'Aluno'; <-- Should be singular. My mistake
    parent::beforeFilter();

}
```

**UPDATE FOR CAKE2**

```
// Place in beforeFilter() of AppController.php

$this->Auth->authenticate = array(
    'Form' => array(
        'userModel' => 'Aluno'
    )
);
```

Your problem is because you are not telling cake what to use for a user table. This is why your first instance works, and the second does not.

Comment: You may or may not need the `parent::beforeFilter();`... I usually leave it in, but someone feel free to correct me on that.

Comment: I did what you told me to, but cake still not generating queries. Any other idea?

Comment: What exactly do you mean, 'it isn't generating queries'?

Comment: At the bottom of the default CakePHP pages, we have a sql_dump that return the query its processing at this request, right?
When I use 'Users' it works fine. When I change the name of Controllers and Models, it returns me no query, showing nothin at the bottom of the page when i hit 'LOGIN'. "(default) 0 query took ms".

Comment: Are you logging in successfully? You have a redirect set in your login action which is probably redirecting you away from the page with the query results to a new page. If you want to see your query resutls, set `'loginRedirect'=>false

Comment: Sorry - `$this->Auth->autoRedirect = false;`

Comment: No, Barry. I'm getting a 'Incorrect user or password' message when i hit login.
I have two fresh cakephp directories with diferent databases. In one i'm using 'UsersController' and 'User' model. In the other i'm using 'AlunosController' and 'Aluno' model, with the codes i've posted above. This is the only difference between this two installations.
In the first i'm able to login, and when i type a user that does not exists, it returns me the User and pass error and the QUERY that it used to talk to the db.
In the second installation, it returns me only the flash msg, and NO QUERY. Got it now?

Comment: Try my example again, I had it plural, should be singular `Aluno`

Comment: I've already tried in singular, Barry, and no success.
This property of Auth still exists in 2.0 version?
Have a look at http://api20.cakephp.org/class/auth-component, and see that it is not there anymore.

Comment: Barry you are the maan! Thanks a million for your help.  Now i can go on with the project. :D

Comment: Great :) Accept the answer if you feel it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Aluno', array('action' => 'login'));
```

to:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Alunos', array('url' => 'alunos/login'));
```

To call Alunos Controller's login() method.